# How to send parameters to scoreboard

Tags: c#, parameters

On the application I'm building for a cyclist race, where as cyclists go over the finish line, I have to enter the time (hours, mins, secs) and click the finish button. Once I click the finish button, I want this information to be displayed in lblScoreboard as:

Competitive cyclist No. 1 has completed in 1:23:49

Then as another cyclists time has been entered, the lblScoreboard should look like:

Competitive cyclist No. 1 has completed in 1:23:49
Competitive cyclist No. 9 has completed in 1:20:30

The code I've used in my 'Finished' button is:

```
lblCyclistsFinished.Text = finishLine.Scoreboard(currentCyc);
```

and the code behind the FinishLine class is:

```
class FinishLine
{
    public string Scoreboard(Cyclists cyc)
    {
        String msg;

        msg = cyc.ToString();

        return msg;
    }
}
```

However, with the code in FinishLine, it will display one result, but as soon as I enter a new result; it replaces the first one so there's only ever 1 result displayed.

The information I want passed is: Type + "No. " + Number + " has completed in " + Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs;

Comment: so you want multiple lines in your label ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lblCyclistsFinished.Text += "\n" + finishLine.Scoreboard(currentCyc);
```

the `"\n"` is the newline character. for reference.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is this

```
 lblCyclistsFinished.Text += finishLine.Scoreboard(currentCyc) + Environment.NewLine();
```